# Blaze linear algebra library?

Tags: linear-algebra, reference-request, c++

The paper "Expression Templates Revisited: A Performance Analysis of Current Methodologies" in SIAM Journal of Scientific Computing references the "Blaze" linear algebra library. I haven't heard of it before, and can't seem to find online references. (The obvious google searches are giving the above paper back.)

So what is this library and where I can I learn more about it?

Comment: @cjs Have you tried contacting the authors of the paper? Or the author of reference 10 in the paper you mention?

Comment: @Ali Nothing is wrong with the paper, AFAIK. I just didn't see a reference for the Blaze library in the paper.

Comment: @GertVdE I have not. I assumed it's commonly known in the numerical linear algebra community, and found it really annoying that the answer wasn't a simple google search away. Simplest to just answer it once and for all on and overflow-type site.

Comment: @cjs I'm not a Lin Alg specialist but Blaze doesn't ring a bell at all. And the authors are also unknown to me. Sorry

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It seems that the library was just [officially released on NA Digest](http://www.netlib.org/na-digest-html/12/v12n35.html#1). The [source code](http://blaze-lib.googlecode.com/files/blaze-1.0.tar.gz) and [documentation](http://blaze-lib.googlecode.com/files/blaze-docu-1.0.tar.gz) are available on [Google Code](http://code.google.com/p/blaze-lib/).

Answer (score 9):

#### Original answer (May 2012)

As far as I am concerned, the Blaze library has not been publicly released.  A link to the software as well as the license for its use should have both been in the paper.

If you're interested in a modern, freely available, numerical linear algebra library that heavily leverages expression templates, I recommend [Eigen](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/index.php?title=Main_Page).

---

#### Update (August 2012)

Blaze has been released, see [Jack's answer](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/a/3145/9) for more details.  I still personally recommend Eigen for those interested in working in numerical linear algebra with C++, but I'm glad to see a new openly released package in this space.

Comment: "Talk is cheap. Show me the code." -- Linus Torvalds

Answer (score 4):

I have never heard of Blaze. However, after reading a bit in the article and searching for the namespace used, I found the physics library at one of the author's [home page](http://www10.informatik.uni-erlangen.de/~iglberger/). As the paper says on p. 2

> This “smart” ET
>   methodology is implemented in the Blaze library that was developed in context of the pe physics engine

Which I take to mean that Blaze is the part of this PE library which does matrix computations. While the website says that the library has "complete documentation", I was unable to find neither library nor documentation on the web site. I think your only option is sending an email.